# CodeArtifact setting error - sts:GetServiceBearerToken

Tags: amazon-web-services

Im trying to set CodeArtifact so that I created domain and repository by manual. But whenever I put command line to access repo it give me back error message like below. Would you help me?
I already add a "AWSCodeArtifactAdminAccess" permission and inline permission code below on IAM Identity Center

`Command line : aws codeartifact login --tool npm --repository npm-store --domain domain-npm --domain-owner 111111111 --region us-east-1`

`Error msg : when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: User: arn:aws:iam::111111111:root is not authorized to perform: sts:GetServiceBearerToken on resource: arn:aws:iam::111111111:root`

```
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Action": [
            "codeartifact:*"
         ],
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Resource": "*"
      },
      {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": "sts:GetServiceBearerToken",
         "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
               "StringEquals": {
                  "sts:AWSServiceName": "codeartifact.amazonaws.com"
               }
            }
      }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.
I was trying to get access to codeartifact repo from EC2 without login(aws configure).
I assigned a Access keys to a user account and then tried it again after login, it worked.